# Why does the OnSuccess method of getPlayersClient() never run?

Tags: java, android

When integrating Google Play Games Sign-in, I needed to get the player name for my app, but the `getCurrentPlayer()` task never completed (`playerName` is perpetually `null`). `OnActivityResult` is ran from a `startActivityForResult` with the intent from the `getSignInIntent()` method of a GoogleSignInClient.

Here's the relevant code from `onActivityResult` (`playerName` is Global):

```
@Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from signInClient
    if (requestCode == SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> resTask =
                GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        if (resTask.isSuccessful()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount resAcct = resTask.getResult();
            PlayersClient playersClient = Games.getPlayersClient(this, resAcct);
            playersClient.getCurrentPlayer()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Player>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Player taskPlayer) {
                            playerName = taskPlayer.getName();
                        }
                    });
            while(playerName==null){
                Log.d("OH GOD WHY", "WHY???");
            }
            //Do something with the name
            ...
        }  else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to sign in. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Before using `OnSuccess`, I was using `OnComplete`, but that never ran either (the `isSuccessful()` check never ran here):

```
playersClient.getCurrentPlayer()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Player>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<Player> pTask) {
            if(pTask.isSuccessful()){
                Player player = pTask.getResult();
                playerName = player.getName();
            } else {
                //Handle error
                ...
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a failure listener by adding the  `addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener)` callback ?

Comment: @AlexMok I tried, but it didn't run either.

Comment: @Kornel Do you still see the issue?

Comment: @Ayyappa I had to turn the OnCompleteListener into an AsyncTask and do the processing in onPostExecute, since the while() loop in the above code prevented the listener from running at all, since it wasn't on a different thread.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the info.
Can you please share once how you have achieved it? I was waiting for the task but on some devices its returning null but on some devices it seems to be fine.

I wasn't using any while loop but just relying on the task to get completed.